# GCD and Code reusability in IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have method named dataLoadingForChallenges. In that, in turn I am calling another two methods when required. I am using this method two to three times in my class for handling different events and in one event I wanna call this method asynchronously in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Is the below code acceptable. I don't want to paste all the code from dataLoadingForChallenges into this GCD block. What is the way to call reusable method from GCD block.

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(q, ^{
            [self dataLoadingForChallenges];
                 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encapsulate that one method call, or even the two larger onces, in a block that you own.  Then your dispatch blocks would be mildly cleaner, and the block can be fired off at any time:

```
typedef void (^DataLoadBlock)();

@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, copy) DataLoadBlock dataLoadBlock;

@end

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    //Avoid a retain cycle with blocks that we own referencing self
    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    _dataLoadBlock = ^{
        id blockSelf = weakSelf;
        [blockSelf dataLoadingForChallenges];
        //Or put your other two messages, or even the bodies of those methods in the block.
    };
    return self;
}

- (void)loadData {
    dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(q, self.dataLoadBlock);
}
```

Comment: Hi @CodaFi, Could you please give some more information. when will be this init method will be called. Also please provide any link/tutorial that may help me. Thanks for reply

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti This is pseudo-code.  You honestly can't expect me to integrate a Stack Overflow answer perfectly with your codebase.  Also, I've explained all I can in regards to your question.  If you'd like a tutorial, ask a different question.

Comment: Probably someone who wanted fish instead of a fishing lesson.